# Flash - AS2 - Call an Object in the parameters of a Function

Tags: arrays, actionscript-2

In Flash, AS2, I am hoping to use the parameters of a function to refer to the name of an excisting object/table/array.

```
myNumbers=[1,2];
myLetters=[a,b];
function myCombine(myCombinedListName:Object, myLista:Object, myListb:Object){
myCombinedListName=myLista.concat(myListb)
}
myCombine(myNewList,myNumbers,myLetters);
```

Any idea how to do this, as this isn't working?

Thanks!
Laurens

**Update**: It seems the main question is, how to refer to an object named within a parameter:

```
function myCreate(myNewObject:Object){
myNewObject = "Hello World";
}
myFunction(myCreatedObject);
trace(myCreatedObject);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered one alternative way to achieve the same goal, using `return`.

```
function myCreate(){
return "Hello World!";
}
myCreatedObject = myCreate();
trace(myCreatedObject);
```